# Accessing items in odict_items

Tags: python

I have  odict_items that is looking like below. Here is the printed output of `Ordereddict` items that I have

```
odict_items([('S.No', '1'), ('Name', 'Ventura'), ('Location', 'Ph'), ('OL', 'ML'), ('Tech', 'IT'), ('Value', 223)])
odict_items([('S.No', '4'), ('Name', 'Ventura'), ('Location', 'Ph'), ('OL', 'ML'), ('Tech', 'IT'), ('Value', 223)])
odict_items([('S.No', '15'), ('Name', 'Ventura'), ('Location', 'Ph'), ('OL', 'ML'), ('Tech', 'IT'), ('Value', 223)])
```

How can I access the `S.No` key from each item and group the values 1, 4, 15?

Comment: Can you provide the expected result and what you have tried so far for this issue?

Comment: I feel I should also say that I don't think most people will immediately understand that you're printing the result of `d.item()` where `d` is an `OrderedDict` instance here. I don't think the type `odict_items` is commonly used directly by anyone.

Comment: edited the question, i would like to access `S.No` key of each item and get the values `1,4,15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to assume here that you have something similar to the following situation at some point:

```
ods = [ OrderedDict(<your data>), OrderedDict(<your data>), OrderedDict(<your data>) ]
for d in ods:
    print(d.items())
```

If you still have the dictionaries these came from, you can and should access the value using `d['S.No']`.

If for some reason you do not still have the `OrderedDict`s themselves, you can make a function to get the value:

```
def get_sno(od_items):
    for item in od_items:
        if item[0] == 'S.No':
            return item[1]
    return None
```

Used as such:

```
snos = []
for d in ods:
    snos.append(get_sno(d.item()) # preferably snos.append(d['S.No']) instead
```